# php webclient open source without popup serverconfiguration

Tags: php, open-source

Is there any open source web client  php application without popup server configuration ,

Am looking open source web client application ,

I dont want imap, pop3 or any protocol suppert application ,

Simply i want intra net message service applications ,

Thanks
Bharanikumar

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "web client application" nor "popup server configuration". Can you please specify what exactly the application that you're looking for needs to do?

Comment: I think he needs a chat or messaging application...

Comment: we running small organisation, around 20 employee..
we dont have access the internet..so we want to message service between employee. that application not depend the internet..

Finally my expectation is ..intranet message service application...sending mails, receving mails, chat ...

Comment: hi  Spiro...yes...if both means am happy
but it should never depend emails and internet...(not depend any thing like  imap,pop3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a chat or messaging application, a searh on google will bring noumerous results ([here for example](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php+chat+application&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=))

You can also look for ajax applications ([here for example](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ajax+messaging))

If it is not what you are looking for, please be more specific in your question as it is not very clear.

Comment: we running small organisation, around 20 employee..
we dont have access the internet..so we want to message service between employee. that application not depend the internet..

Finally my expectation is ..intranet message service application...sending mails, receving mails, chat ...

Comment: sending and receiving email requires internet connection, unless you are just looking for a platform that will enable you to exchange messages within your intranet, something like a forum. In any case, you will first need a server in your intranet to host this. I am not sure if there is a system out there that will enable you to what you are looking for in a bundle, you can still have seperate applications like one of the messaging systems mentioned above and maybe a bb/forum application for messages, which can also be hosted in an intranet. Whatever your choice, you will require a server!

Comment: A forum application could be something like phpbb (http://www.phpbb.com/)

Comment: DB enought know.. i said ..i dont want to use internet....simply i say to you...my interatcion/communication between inside office staff. so we can use the database...correct ?
I dont want message in my mail inbox..(like gmail,yahoo)